# Cumulative sum & several filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I think I have a simple question, but I'm currently stuck. I uploaded an example file here:
https://ufile.io/7iv97
I want the graph to show a cumulative sum, the thing is: It should calculate from the beginning of the data source until the date on the filter.
The problem is: When my filter does not cover the data since the beginning, the cumulative sum is calculated since the starting date of the filter (I want the cumulative sum to ignore it)
I guess this is simple but I couldnt solve it, so I made a simple example to make it easier to answer my question.

It shows 25 when the filter covers the entire period, but less when I move the filter beyond the starting date:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your cumulative sum displayed?

Comment: The two measures I made should be cumulative sums